# Restrict user and guest actions for sending messages

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am building a site (with Cakephp) where users will be able to send sms messages. 
Registered users will have more rights than guests. Lets say guests are allowed to send 5 messages every 24 hours while registered can send 20.

How do I restrict them?

So, for guests, i would need to identify them, should i do it with ip address, session, cookie.. maybe with a mix of all? 
Do i store guest information in database, a file or what?
If i store them in database, would i need to truncate that table every 24 hours...?

As for registered users, same thing applies. Should i track message counter in db, session, file... what would be the easiest way?

Comment: Are you registering the users in your system?

Comment: Yes, registered users can log in with phone number and password.

Comment: then create a table of roles and these roles will be associated to the user and user table has field called counter as soon as the user tries to send the message this will increase the counter and check if user is registered and does not  have the role of guest if its guest pop the message saying you have used your limit

Comment: i would need a way to monitor how much messages user has sent in last 24 hours, but also to restrict him so he cant be able to send 5 messages as a guests, and few minutes later when he logs in, again be able to send 20 more messages. So i need to have a reliable way to identify each user whether logged or guest, and restrict him upon that..

Comment: you can expire the session of guest after one hour and make the counter field of database zero